# How to prevent lupdate to remove some entrie from my translation files?

Tags: qml, translation

I have added some manual entries in my `.ts` files that are removed every time I run the `lupdate.exe` command.

```
lupdate.exe .. -no-obsolete -locations absolute -ts locale_en.ts locale_fr.ts
```

I would like `lupdate.exe` to add the missing entries, to clean the obsolete ones, **but preserving the manual entries** (that are corresponding to strings to be translated but which translation occurs through a function and not a direct call to either `qsTr` or `qTranslate`).

Is this possible ?

---

##### My context:

I'm in a pure qml solution without any C backend, without any build or make mechanism. `lupdate.exe` and `lrelease.exe` are called manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extra translation source (TS) file for the manual entries called `additional_locale_fr.ts` and merge it with the one generated by `lupdate`, e.g. `locale_fr.ts` by using `lconvert`.

```
lconvert -i additional_locale_fr.ts locale_fr.ts -o all_locale_fr.ts
```

([Merge translation files (.ts) with existing .ts files using QT Utilities (lconvert)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527556/525038))

Also interesting in this context [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31892150/525038).

---

You could also use `QT_TR_NOOP()` around your strings in the function. Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-internationalization.html#7-use-qt-tr-noop-for-translatable-data-text-strings) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#qsTranslate-method).

> QT_TR_NOOP is used in conjunction with the dynamic translation
> functions qsTr() and qsTranslate(). It identifies a string as
> requiring translation (so it can be identified by lupdate), but leaves
> the actual translation to the dynamic functions.